# URL clickable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array of contacts, with array websites (object) I would like to display clickable URL format using Jquery.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < contacts[contactIndex].webAddresses.length; i++) {

            var contactFieldWebsites = $(document.createElement('span')).attr({
                class : 'contactFieldWebsites'
            }).html(newOrUpdatedOrNone(contacts[contactIndex].webAddresses[i])+
                    ('href' contacts[contactIndex].webAddresses[i].url) + ' ('
                            + contacts[contactIndex].webAddresses[i].kind + ')'+'<br/>');
            contactDiv.append(contactFieldWebsites);

        }
```

Here I just load url whereas I would like to be able to to click on url and redirect me on selected website thx

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend to use `attr()` method to update the anchor attributes.

```
        var currentContact = contacts[contactIndex];
        for ( var i = 0; i < currentContact.webAddresses.length; i++) {
            var webAddress = currentContact.webAddresses[i];
            var contactFieldWebsites = $('<span/>')
                .addClass('contactFieldWebsites')
                .text('(' + webAddress.kind + ')');
            if (newOrUpdatedOrNone(webAddress )){
                var link = $('<a />')
                    .attr({'href': webAddress .url})
                    .text(webAddress.url)
                    .appendTo(contactFieldWebsites);
            }
            contactDiv.append(contactFieldWebsites);

        }
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this results :

CONTACT NAME
contact@mail (work)
+33 6 74 73 XX 00 (mobile)
+33 1 45 49 XX OO (work)
google.com (work)      <== URL clickable who will load google page 

Thx

Comment: ok, so only the url  would be clickable. What newOrUpdatedOrNone() method does?

Comment: yes, to check if contact's website is udapted, new or nothing

Comment: How can I can function newOrUpdatetorNone now ?

Comment: i whould do a check before doing the var link = ...., and doing it only if newOrUpdatedOrNone(contacts[contactIndex].webAddresses[i]) returns true, i will update the example with a new function

Answer (score 1):

Since you have jQuery, you can chain a click event to your span element on creation (I'm also changing how you create the span to `$("<span/>")`):

```
 var contactFieldWebsites = $("<span/>").attr({class : 'contactFieldWebsites'})
 .html(newOrUpdatedOrNone(contacts[contactIndex].webAddresses[i]) + ('href' contacts[contactIndex].webAddresses[i].url) + ' (' + contacts[contactIndex].webAddresses[i].kind + ')'+'<br/>')
 .click(function() {
     location.href = "your new href goes here";
 });
 contactDiv.append(contactFieldWebsites);
```

Here's a demo showing the concept of adding a clickable function to a newly created element (and appending to a container): http://jsfiddle.net/zRLfE/

Comment: I'm trying to get this results :

CONTACT NAME
google.com (work)      <== URL clickable who will load google page 

Thx